# Can't create/save changes in shapefiles on QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing, error

I can't create or edit shapes in `QGIS`, the files are created on my system but cannot "fill" it with the features. I'm using `QGIS` 2.14.2 64bit Windows 7

This is the error I get when trying to save a new feature to an existing shapefile:

> alriscin_ETRS89: Error de OGR creating the object -2: Error in
>   psSHP->sHooks.FSeek() while writing object to .shp file.

Comment: If you save the shp to a new shp and try editing new shp do you still receive same error?

Comment: The error "Error in psSHP->sHooks.FSeek() while writing object to .shp file." might be related to shp file size limit in OGR, What is the size of your file you are trying to edit?

Comment: I've hit this limit before. I think shapefiles are limited to 2Gb (even if you're using a 64bit OS). You might be better off importing what you do have into PostgreSQL with `shp2pgsql` and working with PostgreSQL layers.

Comment: When i try to save a shape file to a new shape file, it creates the files on the computer (shp, dbf, etc) but without the features inside.

Comment: The error is with any size of file, from 1KB to any...

Comment: Connecting to postgis goes ok, but for my work, in order of coworking, i need to create new shape files.

Comment: Do you have full write access to the target folder?

Comment: Yes, i do have full access

Comment: Does this happen with any shapefile or just this specific one? Would it be possible to upload your shapefile to a public server so that it could be tested by others?

Comment: It happens with all shape files.i'm probing a public one, you can download here if you want to try. http://www.gencat.cat/agricultura/sig/bases/alriscin.zip

Comment: @JoanBachAguirre - Sorry but can't replicate your issue, it works for me using `QGIS 2.14.1 for Win7 64-bit`. Perhaps reinstall QGIS? Hopefully others could test this with 2.14.2.

Comment: I can edit and add features into your file no problem in 2.14.2. Maybe some plugin? I would try to rename plugins folder to start qgis without plugins and test it.